# How do we Check if there are some avro files available inside a HDFS folder?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have some avro files inside HDFS folder /user/data/output_files/file_2017-10-18

```
scala> val hdfsLoc ="/user/data/output_files/file_2017-10-18/*.avro"
hdfsLoc: String = /user/data/output_files/file_2017-10-18/*.avro

scala>  val conf = new Configuration()

scala>   val fs  = FileSystem.get(conf)

scala> val result = fs.exists(new Path(hdfsLoc))
result: Boolean = false
```

The above code gives result as false . It says there is no avro files  inside that HDFS folder

If I give the full name of avro file , then it returns true

```
scala>  val hdfsLoc ="/user/data/output_files/file_2017-10-18/part-r-00000-ed937f14-c7d1-480a-9c79-1cda3db4e6ce.avro"
hdfsLoc: String = /user/data/output_files/file_2017-10-18/part-r-00000-ed937f14-c7d1-480a-9c79-1cda3db4e6ce.avro

scala> val result = fs.exists(new Path(hdfsLoc))
result: Boolean = true
```

How do I ensure that there are  one or more avro files inside a HDFS folder?

Comment: If the avro files are the result of a previous MapReduce or spark job, you can look for the _SUCCESS file in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileSystem` API has a  different function called `globStatus` which allows you to use wildcards.

It returns `Array[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus]`

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(Sc.hadoopConfiguration)

fs.globStatus(new Path("/user/data/output_files/file_2017-10-18/*.avro")).length match {
    case x: Int if (x>0) => doSomethingWhenAvroFileExists()
    case _ => doSomethingWhenNoAvroFilesExist()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems FileSystem doesn't support wildcards. The workaround should be as below though it looks nasty.

```
 val list = fs.listFiles(new Path("/test/"), true)

 var result=false

 while(list.hasNext()){
   if(list.next().getPath.getName.endsWith(".avro"))
     result=true
 }
```